# Recyclerview with Staggered Grid LayMan

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I want to achieve the black arrow exit gate with respect to the seat, as the arrow key is present in the individual seat detail object.
I am using a runtime RecyclerView with staggered GridLayoutManager to populate seat, but cannot achieve the black exit gate arrow.

[image]

Comment: how have you printed the serial number on the left? is it part of same recyclerview? if yes then you can add more columns in recyclerview to print arrow at specified cell. if no, let me know.

Comment: Serial number on the left in another layout, the layout implementation is using framelayout as super parent, linear layout (parent) for seat recyclerview and left serial number as a sibling of previous linear layout.